# Spring WorkManagerTaskExecutor cannot initialize in websphere

Tags: spring, websphere, workmanagers, commonj

i want use Websphere work manager for executing async jobs in jee context but i have problem with creating spring WorkManager.

bean definition:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">     <property name="workManagerName" value="wm/default" /> </bean>
```

this definition i found in websphere help. But problem is this ends with noClassDefFound. I noticed pckg `org.springframework.scheduling.commonj` is missing from spring-context since version 2.x.x

Is it replaced with `org.springframework.jca.work.WorkManagerTaskExecutor` ?

when i use this other spring class, i get error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException:
>   Object of type [class com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkManagerImpl]
>   available at JNDI location [wm/default] is not assignable to
>   [javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager]

so whats deal here? thx

was - 7.0.0.23
spring - 3.1.2

Comment: As far as I can see the class is still there in `spring-context-support` jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor` resides in `spring-context-support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: my bad, i was using spring-context in maven.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration succeeds with `javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager` in `applicationContext-service.xml` in deployment.....

In my case deployment fails for bean injection `org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor` as it fails to take WorkManager JNDI Configured in Application Server.... I just replaced `javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager`. And so far it is success deployment.

I yet to see application works fine with it.

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager">
    <property name="workManagerName" value="wm/default" /> 
</bean>
```

Comment: `javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager` is a Interface. As it is a interface it didn't worked out. Instead `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` we can go for `org.springframework.jca.work.jboss.JBossWorkManagerTaskExecutor`, it is supported in `Spring 2.5` onwards

Comment: in my case it is JBoss.... Excerpt from Spring 2.5 java doc.... Note: At the time of this writing, the `CommonJ WorkManager` facility is only supported on IBM `WebSphere 6.0+` and BEA `WebLogic 9.0+`, despite being such a crucial API for an application server. (There is a similar facility available on `WebSphere 5.1 Enterprise`, though, which we will discuss below.)

On JBoss and GlassFish, a similar facility is available through the JCA WorkManager. See the `JBossWorkManagerTaskExecutor` `GlassFishWorkManagerTaskExecutor classes` which are the direct equivalent of this CommonJ adapter class.

Comment: From Spring 4.1.6 java doc... I find this _Note: On the upcoming EE 7 compliant versions of WebLogic and WebSphere, a DefaultManagedTaskExecutor should be preferred, following JSR-236 support in Java EE 7._

Answer (score 0):

In our scenario we were managed it by **ThreadPoolTaskExecutor** instead of *WorkManagerTaskExecutor*

Here is configuration that comes in `ApplicationContext.xml`

```
<!-- 
<bean id="rtSenderTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
    <property name="workManagerName">
        <value>${org.quartz.threadPool.jndi}</value>
    </property>
</bean> -->

<!-- Local Thread Pool -->    
<bean id="rtSenderTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="${org.quartz.threadPool.corePoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${org.quartz.threadPool.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="${org.quartz.threadPool.queueCapacity}" />
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="${org.quartz.threadPool.keepAliveSeconds}"></property>
</bean>
```